# PendingIntent not working after colsing activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an application to send SMS in android.

I also need to find if message is delivered or not. I have tried to register a receiver to find Delivering SMS , It's working very well if I don't stop activity until sms is delivered. But if I close activity before delivering message , delivery receiver will not work.

what should I do?

here is what i have done(Inside a function in my Activity):

```
try
{
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

String to = "5556";
String body = "Test Message";

String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";


PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                default:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}, new IntentFilter(SENT));


registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;                        
        }
    }
}, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

smsManager.sendTextMessage(to.getText().toString(), null, body.getText().toString(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered dynamically in your `Activity`, and is therefore tied to the `Activity`'s lifecycle. To receive broadcasts even when your `Activity` is not running, you need to statically register your `BroadcastReceiver` class in your manifest.

Note that you can use the same `BroadcastReceiver` class for both your Sent and Delivered broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks for answer , I am a beginner . Do you have any code samples?

Comment: By the way , if I need to register BroadcastReceiver with an extra string on It,s name , for example , ("com.mycompany.myapp.SMS_SENT" + id) what should I do?

Comment: using same name for action cause problem when sending more than one message , I have made a question about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996638/